# Debugging Tomcat in Docker container

Tags: debugging, tomcat, intellij-idea, jpda

I have a CoreOS running in Vagrant. Vagrant private network IP is 192.168.111.1. Inside a CoreOS is a docker container with Tomcat 8.0.32. Pretty much everything works ok (app deployment etc.) just debugging does not. Tomcat is mapped to 8080 port and the JPDA port should be 8000.

### Facts

Tomcat JPDA is configured with:

```
JDPA_OPTS -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000
```

It starts with `catalina.sh jpda start` command. The output in the console when running it with `docker-compose` is:

```
tomcat | Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
```

From the container info I assume that ports are mapped as they should:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE       COMMAND      CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
dcae1e0148f8        tomcat      "/run.sh"    8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes        0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   tomcat
```

My docker image is based on this [Dockerfile](https://github.com/pietvandongen/docker-tomcat-development).

### Problem

When trying to run Remote debug configuration (screenshot below) I get the error `Error running Debug: Unable to open debugger port (192.168.111.1:8000): java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused"`. I've tried everything from changing various configuration but no luck. Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is the command I use for this:

```
docker run -it --rm \
  -e JPDA_ADDRESS=8000 \
  -e JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket \
  -p 8888:8080 \
  -p 9000:8000 \
  -v D:/tc/conf/tomcat-users.xml:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml \
  tomcat:8.0 \
  /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh jpda run
```

Explanation

- *-e JPDA_ADDRESS=8000*
  debugging port in container, passed as environment variable
- *-e JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket*
  transport type for debugging as socket, passed as environment variable
- *-p 8888:8080*
   expose tomcat port 8080 on host as port 8888
- *-p 9000:8000*
   expose java debugging port 8000 on host as port 9000
- *-v {host-file}:{container-file}*
  overwrite tomcat-user.xml with my local on, since I need access to the manager api
  omit this line if this isn't necessary for your use case
- *tomcat:8.0*
  see https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/
- */usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh jpda run*
  command to run in the container

Comment: Setting JPDA_ADDRESS is crucial for making this work in docker. Tomcat defaults to binding against localhost instead of 0.0.0.0 so the debug port cannot be exposed.

Comment: @tstevens, yes, yes, yes. Very helpful. To be more specific: -e JPDA_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8000

Comment: For JDK 9+, see the answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55745249/840714. You need `JPDA_ADDRESS=*:<PORT>`.

Answer (score 17):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, apparently because I was using Java 11. It seems that if you're using Java 9 or newer, you need to specify the JPDA address like this:

```
JPDA_ADDRESS=*:8100
```

Comment: Thanks, caught this bug with: openjdk:8u131-jre-alpine

Answer (score 10):

You can always update the `Dockerfile` to something like the following: -

```
FROM tomcat:8-jre8
MAINTAINER me

ADD target/app.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war

ENV JPDA_ADDRESS="8000"
ENV JPDA_TRANSPORT="dt_socket"

EXPOSE 8080 8000
ENTRYPOINT ["catalina.sh", "jpda", "run"]
```

This does mean though that your docker file has debug on by default which is probably not suited to a production environment.

Answer (score 4):

Try add to your Dockerfile

```
ENV JPDA_ADDRESS=8000
ENV JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
```

It works for me

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that port 8080 is exposed to IntelliJ for connection. That is while running docker you shall require something like `docker run -p 8080:8080`

For example, I am able to achieve the similar requirement like this by doing below mentioned steps/checks.

This is what my docker run command looks like:

```
sudo docker run --privileged=true -d -p 63375:63375 -p 63372:8080 -v /tmp/:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/config <container name>:<tag>
```

NOTE: I am exposing an extra port 63375 on container and on my host both. The same port I am using in CATALINA_OPTS below.

This is what my entry point (for the image that I am building) looks like. NOTE: I am using CATALINA_OPTS. Also, I am using maven to create image so below is excrept from pom.xml.

```
<entryPoint>
    <shell>cd /usr/local/tomcat/bin; CATALINA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=63375,server=y,suspend=n" catalina.sh run</shell>
</entryPoint>
```

Comment: In the Facts section is container info that indicates that the tomcat ports are exposed correctly. Using `lsof` command i've checked that the port 8000 was free. I believe that the JPDA_OPTS are also configured correctly as the log is suggesting. Thanks for trying anyway.

Comment: What was the docker command you used to run the container ? That is important here. I am not sure when you are saying port was free, do you mean it was open and listening ? Also, where it was free/open  - inside container  OR on the host (where you are probably running the intellij) which is running the container ?

Comment: Free/open port on the host: to make sure that no other app is taking it.
Tomcat container runs with docker-compose (along with other containers). Ports are exposed in the docker-compose file. Run command is default (from the image `catalina.sh jpda run`).

Comment: I meant docker run command specially `-p <hostPort>:<containerPort> part.`

Comment: I use docker-compose, therefore, there is no docker run command in my case. However, `docker-compose port` and `docker run -p` are the same thing (8000:8000 and 8080:8080).

Comment: Ahhh.. I see. I am unaware about the compose. But the exception that intellij is telling is indicator of port mapping only.

Comment: There must be something else. Otherwise I would not be able to deploy the app to the server through 8080 port.

Comment: firewall iptables ?? just guessing

Answer (score 1):

I resolved a similar, if not the same, issue when using docker-compose.

It involved the environment variables not being passed properly from the docker-compose.yml file.

[See my stack overflow issue:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45383645/remote-debugging-with-jpda-wont-connect-to-tomcat-through-eclipse-when-using-do/45384149#45384149)

Answer (score 1):

For me, it's cleaner this way:

```
docker run -e JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n" -p 8000:8000 tomcat:8.5-jdk8
```

This way, you don't have to modify your container Dockerfile.

Explanation: all java versions check the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS environment variable: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/envvars002.html

Answer (score 0):

I have similar setup in my local environment. I included JPDA_ADDRESS as environment variable in the Dockerfile and recreated the containers.

```
ENV JPDA_ADDRESS 8000

#Expose port 8080, JMX port 13333 & Debug port 8000
EXPOSE 8080 13333 8000

CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```